# How to add onclick to cardview in android to open link in webview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I have list of cards in gridview all are static i want to add onclick to each card and open a link in webview when clicked different link for different card.

Comment: describe your question, show some code

Comment: i removed code something like inside of gridlayout i added 10cardviews into 2columns each card will have image and when i click on image or card it should open link in webview.

Answer (score 0):

https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

use this for reference for onclick item of recyclerview.

**NOTE**

below sentence will be understood, only when you follow the above link

Now after doing all the steps, you will have a method in Activity after implementing the interface. pass the position to the method.

In that method, add switch case, based on position you got, call the webview with that particular uri.